# Error Msg: unknown column in field list in tables with the field

Tags: sql

currently I have the following code, the part I and partII works fine.
However, when I am trying to Union, the two temporary table, it keeps me giving me error message of 
"Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'" even when I have tried quite several time to change the name of the filed 'name' in the temporary table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS inp_cnt AS(
SELECT a.name, count(DISTINCT ad.pub_id) AS c
FROM author AS a
INNER JOIN authored AS ad ON a.id = ad.author_id
INNER JOIN inproceedings AS inp ON ad.pub_id = inp.pub_id
WHERE inp.booktitle = "SIGMOD conference" OR inp.booktitle = "KDD" OR inp.booktitle = "VLDB"
GROUP BY ad.author_id);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ar_cnt AS(
SELECT a.name,  count(DISTINCT ad.pub_id) AS c
FROM author AS a
INNER JOIN authored AS ad ON a.id = ad.author_id
INNER JOIN article AS ar ON ad.pub_id = ar.pub_id
WHERE ar.journal = "PVLDB"
GROUP BY ad.author_id);


SELECT name,sum(c) AS total
FROM (
SELECT name,c FROM inp_cnt
UNION ALL
SELECT name, c FROM ar_cnt
) as tmp
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Can somebody give some hint on this? Am i getting this error msg because name is a special keyword in sql??

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the last query to:

```
SELECT  tmp.name
       ,SUM(tmp.c) AS total
FROM    ( SELECT    name
                   ,c
          FROM      inp_cnt
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    name
                   ,c
          FROM      ar_cnt
        ) AS tmp
GROUP BY tmp.name
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

So you have `tmp.name` in the `Group By`.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried, still doesn't  work.seems that it cannot detect all the 'name' in the query.

Comment: for the inp_cnt and ar_cnt table, I have printed  them out, both of them have the correct name and c in the result.

Comment: @mona, try adding the `tmp.` alias to the `SELECT` portion too.

Comment: hi, it cannot figure out the name from the two temp tables(inp_cnt, ar_cnt)

Comment: If i replace the thrird query with simple query like select name from inp_cnt; it wont work, would it be related to the temporary table?